# Chrome extensions: Anything that can render a tab/page to something static?

Tags: html, chrome, web-browser

I tend to page park on a massive level when doing online research - and often only need the actual, visible content on a parked page, not to further interact with that page.

Is there any way (short of disabling all javascript) to convince chrome to render a page once, put a static html version or even a literal image in the tab, and stop using up further resources either for background javascript or to render it anew when returning to the tab?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) facility to snapshot pages to your Evernote research notes.

This is as simple as right clicking on a page and selecting an option:
[image: Clipping in Evernote]

Once you have selected such a snapshot you can close the page secure in the knowledge that it is in your library and accessible via the web interface, the PC App or the Mobile App. Such notes are saved rendered but complete with the original URL, the date, etc. and can be annotated, tagged, deleted, etc. later.

In a research environment it is awesome as it allows you to organize, cite and even *(on some plans)* collaborate. As well as web content it can handle PDF files, Photos with text (Android). There is a [WebClipper](https://evernote.com/products/webclipper) plugin for Chrome and other browsers, *Safari, Firefox, Edge, IE7+ & Opera*, (IE/Edge is installed with the desktop client). There are also plug-ins available for Outlook & Safari.

There are a number of plans available, *(including free),* for the service with different prices, quotas and tools. It is worth noting that eligible students, *(i.e. those with access to a [recognized educational domain email address](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/222973507)),* may be able to get 50% discount on the premium plan via an [offer page](http://www.evernote.com/students). On the Free plan you can currently have 2 devices registered.